# wonky jquery -- for some users of my site, my changing text does not perform the desired behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

site: deepsteg.com

code

```
if(Data.is_homepage){
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if($(window).scrollTop() < $('#process').offset().top){
                $('.tagline').removeClass('highishzindex');
                $('.tl').html('A superior, open source suite of state-of-the-art steganalysis tools.')
            }
            if($(window).scrollTop() < $('#secondtagline').offset().top &&
                $(window).scrollTop() > $('#process').offset().top ){
                $('.tagline').removeClass('highishzindex');
                $('.tl').text('Not just a project; a movement.')
            }
            if($(window).scrollTop() < $('#thirdtagline').offset().top &&
                $(window).scrollTop() > $('#ending').offset().top ){
                $('.tagline').removeClass('highishzindex');
                $('.tl').text("How far are we?")
            }
            if($(window).scrollTop() < $('#prospects').offset().top + $('#prospects').height()){
                $('.tagline').removeClass('highishzindex');
            }else{
                $('.tagline').addClass('highishzindex');
            }
            if($(window).scrollTop() > $('#prospects').offset().top){

                $('.tl').html("Want to contribute?<p class='seehow wow fadeInDown'><span class='serher'><a href='mailto:self@mikejohnsonjr.com'>Contact</span></a></span>&nbsp;<span class='serher'><a href='http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=#deepsteg'>Chat With Us</a></span>&nbsp;<span class='serher'><a href='https://github.com/mikejohnsonjr/deepsteg'>Github Repo</a></span></p>")
            }
        });
    }
```

pics of undesireable behavior: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/652938397765337098/652939243756453979/Screenshot_2019-12-07_Deepsteg.png

(At the bottom of the page, user is supposed to see "Want to contribute?...")

more undesirable behavior:

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/652938397765337098/652939756233293824/Screenshot_2019-12-07_Deepsteg1.png?width=579&height=597

(one user reported seeing this when scrolling to the bottom then scrolling up a bit)

Any help here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The control statement `if(Data.is_homepage) {...` is the likely culprit. What exactly is `Data` and are you sure it shouldn't be more like: `Data.is('.homepage')`?

Comment: Data is just an object. In home.html i have <script> Data.is_homepage = true </script>. That is all